# Результат в виде таблицы

Tags: python

В Python cоставил вот такую простенькую программу рецепта домашнего вина:

```
box = 10                             # имеющийся объем бродильной емкости 
print(box,'-бродильная емкость, л')
wine_wort = box * 0.85               # будет сусла
print(round(wine_wort, 2), '-будет сусла, л') 
sugarl = wine_wort * 0.142           # процент содержания сахара в сусле из расчета 270 гр/л сусла
print(round(sugarl, 2), '-в т.ч.сахара в сусле, л')
sugarkg = sugarl / 0.62
print(round(sugarkg, 2), '-то есть нужно внести сахара, кг')
juice = wine_wort * 0.86             # процент содержания фруктового сока в сусле
print(round(juice, 2), '-будет фруктового сока в сусле, л')
fruite = juice / 0.6                 # нужно фруктов из расчета выхода сока из  1кг фруктов = 0,6 л  
print(round(fruite, 2), '-нужно фруктов, кг')
```

После запуска программы получаем:

```
1 - бродильная емкость, л  
0.85 - будет сусла,л  
0.12 - в т.ч. сахара в сусле, л  
0.19 - то есть нужно внести сахара, кг  
0.73 - будет фруктового сока в сусле, л  
1.22 - нужно п/я культуры, кг
```

А как записать  этот результат в виде таблицы, и далее, чтобы программа сразу последовательно посчитала на емкости скажем от 1 до 5 л.
Вот так.

```
Емкость,л | Сусло,л | В т.ч.сахара | Нужно сахара | В т.ч. сока | нужно фруктов | в сусле,л | в сусле,кг | кг
                                      
                                
1                   
2                   
3                   
4                   
5
```

Comment: К такому вопросу должна прилагаться бочка вина.

Comment: Можно использовать https://github.com/adamlamers/prettytable

Comment: можно использовать модуль pandas и потом сохранить, например, в excel файл

Comment: @AlexanderKorovin Если сохранять в эксель, то лучше сразу и использовать эксель. Будет быстрее и проще.

Comment: @Эникейщик -  не согласен, вопрос по питону, а pandas дает возможность напечатать таблицу в консоли. Про excel я написал как "бонус" к pandas (к тому же excel файл или другой формат с помощью pandas создается програмно).

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
table = PrettyTable()

box = list(range(1, 6))
wine_wort = [round(i*.85, 2) for i in box]
sugarl = [round(i*.142, 2) for i in box]
sugarkg = [round(i/.62, 2) for i in sugarl]
juice = [round(i*.86, 2) for i in wine_wort]
fruite = [round(i/.6, 2) for i in juice]

columns = {
    'Емкость,л': box,
    'Сусло,л': wine_wort,
    'В т.ч.сахара': sugarl,
    'Нужно сахара': sugarkg,
    'В т.ч. сока': juice,
    'Нужно фруктов': fruite,
}

for key, item in columns.items():
    table.add_column(key, item)

print(table)
```

Comment: кое как разобрался с pip'оном, таблица получилась, но вот хотелось бы получить в графе где количество 2 знака после запятой

Comment: @сергей исправил

Comment: Вообще, через добавление строк (вместо колонок) через add_row было бы нагляднее